# Sortable behaviour (Doctrine extension): position not being saved in the database

Tags: symfony

I have this in my controller:

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectFrontendBundle:Item');

  $item = $repository->find(3);
  $item->setPosition('10');
  var_dump($item->getPosition()); exit(); //this returns 10

  $em->persist($item);
  $em->flush();

  var_dump($item->getPosition()); exit();//this returns 5 

  return $this->render('ProjectBackendBundle:Default:prueba.html.twig');
```

The problem: the new value for position (10) is not being saved in the data base (MySQL).

Im getting this log:

```
 1207 Query SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.position AS position2, t0.image_name AS image_name3, t0.updatedAt AS updatedAt4, t0.slug AS slug5, t0.nombre AS nombre6, t0.activado AS activado7, t0.parent_id AS parent_id8 FROM Item t0 WHERE t0.id = 3
 1207 Query SELECT MAX(i0_.position) AS sclr0 FROM Item i0_
 1207 Query START TRANSACTION
 1207 Query UPDATE Item SET position = 5 WHERE id = 3
 1207 Query commit
 1207 Quit
```

This is my Entity `Item`:

```
<?php
namespace Project\FrontendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subitem", mappedBy="item")
     */
    private $subitems;

    /**
     * @var integer $position
     *
     * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="20M",
     *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"}
     * )
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="item_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     *
     * @var File $image
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="image_name", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string $imageName
     */
    protected $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"nombre"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="nombre")
     */
    protected $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="activado")
     */
    protected $activado = true;


    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set position
     *
     * @param integer $position
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get position
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageName
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set activado
     *
     * @param boolean $activado
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setActivado($activado)
    {
        $this->activado = $activado;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activado
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getActivado()
    {
        return $this->activado;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param \Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item $children
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addChild(\Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item $children)
    {
        $this->children[] = $children;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove children
     *
     * @param \Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item $children
     */
    public function removeChild(\Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item $children)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($children);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item $parent
     * @return Item
     */
    public function setParent(\Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Item 
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add subitems
     *
     * @param \Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Subitem $subitems
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addSubitem(\Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Subitem $subitems)
    {
        $this->subitems[] = $subitems;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove subitems
     *
     * @param \Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Subitem $subitems
     */
    public function removeSubitem(\Project\FrontendBundle\Entity\Subitem $subitems)
    {
        $this->subitems->removeElement($subitems);
    }

    /**
     * Get subitems
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSubitems()
    {
        return $this->subitems;
    }
}
```

Im not getting errors in apache or symfony logs.

Comment: run var_dump($item->getPosition()); exit(); what do you see?

Comment: can you run the command and also post your entity class aswell?

Comment: looks like a **cache issue** to me. Did you clear symfony's and doctrine's cache (apc?) ? Doctrine tries to update with value *5* instead of *10* ... `$item->setPosition('10');` => `UPDATE Item SET position = 5 WHERE id = 3`

Comment: @MatthewAThomas I have updated my question. Which command do you mean?

Comment: @nifr I have cleared the cache but not change..

Comment: run var_dump($item->getPosition()); exit();  just before you persist the object just to see if it has assigned the property its new value

Comment: Doubtful is it is a cache issue.  The SELECT MAX query indicates that the posted code does not match the actual code.  So he has more stuff going on.  I do wonder if passing a string instead of an integer might be causing problems.  Probably not.  Maybe a listener of some sort.

Comment: @MatthewAThomas placing persist() where you said I get 10

Comment: Very odd, seems that there is something going on, can you try persting something else also to see if it is still happening. I have a feeling that the object is being cloned or modified, perhaps by an additional bundle that is attached to your entity. Give that a try and see

Comment: Since your posted code indicated that you are retrieving the item using find, you should not need a persist statement at all.  Persist is only needed for inserting new items though calling it on existing items does not hurt.  Are you sure your posted code really matches your actual code?

Comment: Looks like your VichBundle is doing quite a bit of magic.

Comment: This is just for debugging, try adding PreUpdate on that setFunction and if still the same result try PostUpdate, just to see if that bundle is doing something odd

Comment: @MatthewAThomas sorry, what setFunction?

Comment: @MatthewAThomas where should I add that preUpdate()? inside `Item` class?

Comment: hard to write it in hear so pointing you in the direction example http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: @MatthewAThomas I have added this line  `*@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` as an annotation of my Item class. Then I have added `public function preUpdate() { die("preupdate called"); }` to the same class, but after requesting I dont get that "preupdate called"

Comment: Stop panacking read it carefully you need to add /**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */ above the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62126/discussion-between-ziiweb-and-matthew-a-thomas).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62129/discussion-between-ziiweb-and-matthew-a-thomas).

Comment: 1207 Query SELECT MAX(i0_.position) AS sclr0 FROM Item i0_ how many element you already have?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the Doctrine Sortable behaviour. I have 4 elements, when I try to give a position higher that 5 (6, 7, 8, 9, etc) it converts it to 5 since my last position is 4.